# Warning:unlink() Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

When I call `rrmdir()`, to delete a directory and all its sub folders then it 
gives warning:

> "Warning:unlink(C:\congreaaws\tmp\mfpXeLhshG6puztQbamygpB1CqowIzL7ajS5Se8a\12323\076a12b3-9052-404a-9cd1-cfb62adf62c1\mod.pptx):
>   Resource temporarily unavailable in C:\congreaaws\conversion.php on
>   line 196"

```
function rrmdir($dir) {
  // echo $dir; exit;
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        $objects = scandir($dir);
        foreach ($objects as $object) {
            if ($object != "." && $object != "..") {
                if (is_dir($dir . "/" . $object))
                    rrmdir($dir . "/" . $object);
                else
                    unlink($dir . "/" . $object);
            }
        }
        rmdir($dir);
    }
}
```

Same above function is working in centos but in windows it is not working I used iis server to run php.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use following code, I'm sure it will solve your issues.

**Add this function to your function file**

```
function delete_directory($dirPath){
        $dir = $dirPath;   
        if(is_dir($dir)){
            $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
                new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS), RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST
            );
            foreach($files as $file){
                if ($file->isDir()){
                    rmdir($file->getRealPath());
                }else{
                    unlink($file->getRealPath());
                }
            }
            rmdir($dir);
        }
    }
```

**HOW TO USE**

> delete_directory($dir);